# PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass - Header in Script

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

I am attempting to easily `ByPass` PowerShells `ExecutionPolicy`. I realize one easy fix was to create `runme.ps1` and `script.ps1` and in `runme.ps1` I can `Bypass` the `ExecutionPolicy` and call `script.ps1`. Is there some way to put this in a "header" of a script and have it call itself while `Bypass`ing the `ExecutionPolicy`?

runme.ps1:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\tmp\script.ps1"
```

script.ps1:

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
PAUSE
```

I'm currently working on some sort if "flag" or "tmpfile" logic and having the script call itself, but I wondered if there was a known/better way or even a possible way to have this be a header in all my scripts so end users can just "run w/ powershell" without prompts.

Addendum's to answer's with elaborations on `ExecutionPolicy` are welcome, but let's focus on the question.

Discussions on `ExecutionPolicy` should be focused on the "Security Stack Exchange" and the relevant post is linked here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118553/whats-the-purpose-of-executionpolicy-settings-in-powershell-if-the-bypass

https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/:

> However, it’s important to understand that the setting was never meant
> to be a security control. Instead, it was intended to prevent
> administrators from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: Have you considered just changing the machine- or user-level policy to `RemoteSigned` (or `Unrestricted`)?

Comment: You cannot change the execution policy for scripts from inside a script!!!  ;-)  ... it's like the chicken and the egg problem. ;-) You will have to run the first script with the parameter `-ep ByPass` already as well.

Comment: `adjusting every end users machines is not an option` -How so, what kind of environment are you working with?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Imagine you download a bunch of scripts off the internet to read and learn from - but then you accidentally click one of them, and it turns out to be malware. Wouldn't it be nice if your computer said "you just downloaded this code of the internet, maybe we shouldn't run it?" and you had to deliberately go about executing it if you really wanted to? That's what the Execution Policy is for. Preventing you (and everyone else) from accidental mishaps. That's also why you can bypass it so easily - it works as designed.

Comment: `Also, have you ever worked in a Corporation? Good luck trying to get that policy approved and implemented..`  you can specify for who you want to lower the security and for who you won't  ... that's how the majoirty of the Windows environments work these days.  ;-) Anyway ... usually you roll out a script either with a software deployment solution or with group policies and there you can set the execution policy as you need it.

Comment: Rename `runme.ps1` to `runme.bat` and that will work.  But, otherwise, @Olaf's comment is exactly right: you can't run a PowerShell script to enable running PowerShell scripts so you can run a PowerShell script.

Comment: @Olaf I beg to differ, I changed the policy inside my script with a one-liner which pipes to null and on my script goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\circumvent\industry\standard.ps1" 2>&1>$null
```

I wanted to share scripts and be able to say "right click and run w/ powershell" which is already worse then batch scripts where I say "double click the file" (people always get that one!).

The solution came to me because I had a `PAUSE` in my main script to read console output and I noticed that after my main script called `script.ps1` that I received an additional `PAUSE` prompt from the "main/parent" script. Which made me realize, that the parent script was able to continue after calling child script. Ergo, `call nonexistent script and pipe output to null!` & continue on merrily.

Example Scenario:

The following script wouldn't run via "right-click, Run w/ PowerShell" after a fresh reboot and I got the standard "Execution Policy Prompt":

**script.ps1**

```
Write-Host "Calling Scripts? No Problem!"
PAUSE
```

The following worked after a fresh reboot:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\circumvent\industry\standard.ps1" 2>&1>$null
ECHO "This Script Won't Run Without Line 1" 
ECHO "I had fun to try to circumvent an industry standard" 
ECHO "I Learned a lot about PowerShell ExecutionPolicy"
C:\tmp\script.ps1
PAUSE
```

**Result:**

```
This Script Won't Run Without Line 1
I had fun to try to circumvent an industry standard
I Learned a lot about PowerShell ExecutionPolicy
Calling Scripts? No Problem!
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Update based on @BACON's comment, this is truly only possible with "run w/ powershell" via the "context menu". I tried setting "powershell" as the default app for `.ps1` and not only did it not work, but the context menu removed the "run w/ powershell" option!

Thankfully, end users will have default settings and/or sysadmins will know how to resolve already.

Something I didn't test originally, but wanted to know how "circumventy" this solution really was is try using just `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in the header. This resulted in the script not running, therefor it must be assigned a `-File` but has no effect if File doesn't exist and allows script to continue executing.

Comment: But what runs that `PowerShell.exe` command? The trailing `$null` suggests a PS script, so how is _that_ run? The whole point of execution policies is to require the user/administrator to affirm their answer to "Are you sure you want to execute that?" by performing a deliberate, conscious act somewhere along the line. That could be executing a script's contents interactively, changing the policy, or overriding the policy, as you do with a new `PowerShell.exe` instance. There's nothing being "circumvented" or "bypassed" here; this is just playing within the rules of how execution policies work.

Comment: Right... Except I circumvented the whole "Are you sure you want to execute that?" prompt. I'm so confused how you could imagine this isn't circumventing anything.

Comment: But what runs that PowerShell.exe command? = "right click and run w/ powershell" @BACON

Comment: I didn't say it'd be a literal "Are you sure you want to execute that?" prompt.  See `help about_Run_With_PowerShell` and the value of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\0\Command` to see how it works. That `Run with PowerShell` is not the default action for a `.ps1` file and requires the context menu comports with what I already said: "a deliberate, conscious act" by the user. The reason this isn't circumventing anything is because there's **no escalation of privilege**, these are **documented features**, and "circumvention" doesn't mean "things working exactly as designed."

Comment: @BACON http://static.skaip.org/img/emoticons/180x180/f6fcff/headbang.gif

Answer (score 1):

You can create a some kind of trusted launcher (cmd file, or exe file), that will run powershell with `--ExecutionPolicy ByPass` flag. Or Even you can change behaviour of `double-click` action to run PowerShell with ByPass policy flag always.

However, settings on computer can be hardened by system administrator in `MachinePolicy\ExecutionPolicy` or `UserPolicy\ExecutionPolicy` and you will not be able to override it in normal way.

ExecutionPloicy is configured at 4+1 levels, with priority from High to Low:

```
> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

MachinePolicy (Group Policy)
   UserPolicy (Group Policy)
      Process (Configured using powershell -ExecutionPolicy flag for new process only)
  CurrentUser (User settings)
 LocalMachine (Computer settings)
```

When you run PowerShell with ByPass flag, you actually set `Process`-level ExecutionPolicy that overrides `CurrentUser` and `LocalMachine` setings, but can be hardened at `UserPolicy` or `MachinePolicy` level managed by local or domain Group Policies.

---

Better way is to comfigure user policies using group policy to allow run only `AllSigned` or `RemoteSigned` scripts, generate a certificate `New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type CodeSigning` for 100 years, deploy it using GPO as `Trusted Publisher` per computer and sign using `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` every script you deploy to users.

Comment: I looked today at my org's settings, but interesting to know that it can be overridden by a "higher up" policy, so my efforts can be nullified. I'd be interested to know how this (#12) is effected by that rule tho --> https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/

Comment: It's abnormal functionality, I'd recommend to avoid this. Just contact your IT dept to sign your scripts once or to give you a signing certificate for that purpose.

Comment: I wouldn't ever recommended deploying a 100yr certificate for anything.... Better off with default security settings